# How to know where was created custom post types?

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

guys, i'm working on some website, that works on Wordpress. Previous dev. created custom post types, but i need to know, where are they created to work with em.

What i know in fact is that they not declared in functions.php in my theme. Where to look for em?

Comment: Download the file structure, use a 'Find in files' feature available with many editors to search for `register_post_type(`

Comment: thanks a lot! i never mind, that it could be in such strange place... It was in plugin directory. That plugin manage user roles...

What a strange hierarchy =/

Comment: @ЛысенкоАлексей It is not a strange hierarchy . the plugin is used as a `functionality plugin` and it is actually smart . More than smart - it is the correct and recommended way.  In that way, the custom post type and functionality of the site is not theme-dependent . It will work the same with every theme .

Comment: @obmerk-kronen yeah, i get it. To me looks weird that functional of custom post types realized in custom roles plugin :)

Comment: @ЛысенкоАлексей - but that is the whole point. if it was realized in a theme - the functionality would not have been maintained when a theme is changed . Anyhow, I hope you got it..

Comment: @ObmerkKronen - Perhaps his concern is that the `custom post types` functionality is realised through the `custom roles` plugin.